# Android Google Play App Signing with Multiple Apps

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I work for a large organization with potentially multiple apps that we'd like to release on the Google Play Store.  I like the idea of using [Google App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) rather than managing the signing keys ourselves. After enabling this, each uploaded app gets signed with an upload key, but in the case of multiple apps, do all of them need to be signed with the same upload key or can the upload key be unique per app?  In our organization, there may be multiple different teams that manage their own apps, so having to share the upload key across all these teams would be cumbersome.  Could someone shed some light on how this might work for our situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **same upload key** for different apps. Also, you can use **multiple upload key** for different teams.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for this?